# Why is my application outputting the same result for every new input?

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn

I'm creating an application that predicts the species of the Iris Flower using the Iris Flower dataset. I'm building the application using Flask. I am giving different inputs to the application but I'm getting the different results compared to my kaggle model. I believe that there isn't anything wrong with the Machine Learning part of my code because I've executed it on Kaggle and different inputs resulted in different predicted outputs. I don't seem to understand what is going on and why the output is not changing after I've integrated the machine learning with HTML. As I am a beginner to Flask, it would be greatly appreciated if the explanation is kept simple.

````
```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
from forms import InputForm
from io import StringIO
import pickle


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '0dfd576186d78d2318e8c2987d56ec42'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    form = InputForm()
    return render_template('home.html', form=form)


@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():  
    icd = pd.read_csv("F:\Alekhya\Projects\IrisProject\data\irisdata.csv")
    features = ['sepal_length_cm', 'sepal_width_cm', 'petal_length_cm', 'petal_width_cm']
    X = icd[features]
    y = icd['class']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42, stratify=y)
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=7)
    knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
    pickle.dump(knn, open('model.pkl','wb'))
    model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        pl = request.form['pl']
        sl = request.form['sl']
        pw = request.form['pw']
        sw = request.form['sw']
        df = pd.DataFrame({'sepal_length_cm': [sl], 'sepal_width_cm': [sw], 'petal_length_cm':[pl], 'petal_width_cm':[pw]})
        prediction = model.predict(df)
        return render_template('prediction.html', prediction=prediction[0])
````

**This is my Home.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %} 

    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('predict') }}">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Type the measurements in cm</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.Petal_length.label(class="form-control-label") }}

                    {% if form.Petal_length.errors %}
                        {{ form.Petal_length(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.Petal_length.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        <input name="pl" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text"></input>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.Sepal_length.label(class="form-control-label") }}

                    {% if form.Sepal_length.errors %}
                        {{ form.Sepal_length(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.Sepal_length.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        <input name="sl" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text"v></input>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.Petal_width.label(class="form-control-label") }}

                    {% if form.Petal_width.errors %}
                        {{ form.Petal_width(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.Petal_width.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        <input name="pw" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text"></input>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.Sepal_width.label(class="form-control-label") }}

                    {% if form.Sepal_width.errors %}
                        {{ form.Sepal_width(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.Sepal_width.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        <input name="sw" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text"></input>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white">
            {{ prediction }}
        </div>
        </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**This is my prediction.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %} 

    <div class="content-section">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white">
                {{ prediction }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info"><a href={{ url_for('home') }}>Go Back</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Your model's fine. Try pl = 7
    sl = 3.2
    pw = 4.1
    sw = 1.1

Comment: Those values are giving the output *Iris-versicolor*, which is the same output given by my kaggle kernel. This model tested to be 96% accurate, and when I give inputs of a specific species from the dataset it's not giving the correct output in the application. When I do it on a Kaggle Kernel, with the same values, it is giving the correct prediction. Why is that?

Comment: Yes but I'll get Iris-setosa for all values equal to 1

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're saying. Could you please clarify.

Comment: I ran your code with no problem and with different results. Could you provide your template files? (prediction and home.html)

Comment: It seems like there is no problem with templates, either. It sure gives different results so there is no problem related to giving the same results as you suggested.  The problem is that you don't expect to have a particular result from your input. Are you sure that your model definition is the same as your kaggle kernel? Try giving them the same random seed

Comment: I provided the template files. When pl = 5.6, pw = 2.5, sl = 3.9, sw = 1.1, my Kernel gives the correct prediction as 'iris-virginica' but my model in my flask app is giving iris-versicolor.

Comment: Did you checked your models to be same? Are you using the same rand seed?

Comment: My kaggle kernel and my model are the exact same things. Yes I am using the same.

Comment: Why do you train your model? Save the model from kaggle and just load it. It saves some processing time and you will be sure that your models are the same.

Comment: I saved the model from kaggle and loaded that, but my app is still giving another prediction from that of the kaggle model. What do I do?

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure that inputs in both apps are given right? Maybe you could double check your model inputs or query input in the other app.

Comment: I think I may have found the problem. The dataframe I have created is `df = pd.DataFrame({'sepal_length_cm': [sl], 'sepal_width_cm': [sw], 'petal_length_cm': [pl], 'petal_width_cm': [pw]})` but the output dataframe i'm getting has the order petal length, petal width, sepal length, and sepal width. So my model is getting the wrong order of the measurements. How do I fix this?

Comment: @maanijou I got the required output. It was because my created dataframe was putting my input values in the wrong order. Thank you so much for your help!